# Deploy Android applications for internal company users

Tags: android-emulator, android

I have developed Android application.  Now I want to deliver it to the our company users.  What is the best way to deliver it to the users without publishing Android Market?

I can store APK in the server and send link to the users.  Users can access that link from
their mobiles and download APK to SD card and after install to their phones.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to distribute it publicly, what you said will work. You can provide an APK which users can download to their devices and install directly from the APK. Alternatively, you could install via ADB.

However, this makes upgrading a little trickier down the road.

Comment: can we do it without using another tool? or need another 3rd party tool?

Comment: Some devices may come with a pre-packaged file manager which will allow APKs to be installed (or some flavors of Android may simply be able to recognize and install APKs out-of-the-box). If not, there are freely available ones that do this such as Astro File Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will work for sure. one another way is to send them via mail as a attachment.

Comment: can we do it without using another tool? or need another 3rd party tool?

Comment: I am not getting here meaning of another tool??
But if user can connect mobile to their pc they can use Android Injector tool to inject apk in device

Comment: if you send mail it will directly install & I think it will be best option.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done before is host the APK on Dropbox and provide a public URL to the users to download it. Once they've downloaded it, a popup asks the user if they want to install it. It's pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,what you are trying to do is right but make sure that you also provide the API level for users because your application might not work on earlier API levels.

Answer (score 1):

Simply distributing the .apk to your internal users is probably the easiest way to setup, however you will not benefit from the automatic app updates that Google Play provides.

By now there are a couple of more solutions available, e.g. [Private Channel](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992) (for Google Apps users), Alpha/beta stages for internal distribution (more like a hack..) or complex [MDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) solutions.

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378605/1024108) in [Google Play deployment for internal company user only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371812/google-play-deployment-for-internal-company-user-only) for reference.