# Google Play deployment for internal company user only

Tags: android

Is it possible to deploy an APP to android play store, but only allow internal company user to download the APP. Actually, we can distribute the android APP apk to staff to install, but the version upgrade is difficult for apk distribution.
Don't know if there has any method to do so for allowing internal staff install only

Comment: I am not sure about the playstore, but HockeyApp should allow you to achieve what you need

Comment: The key-word for Google searchs is [MDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) (Mobile Device Management).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Alpha/Beta system for that. You can make a group on GoogleGroups and allow only the email address in it to download the app from playStore. Maybe, it is available in release mod.

Comment: May I know the email address can use other domain address, not gmail.com

Comment: Yes, you can add email address any domain. When you add them, it send an invitation to join the group to this email.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you could use the [Google Play alpha/beta testing & staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) for this, it does feel a lot like a hack/workaround to me.

As far as I know, those are the "official" options for internal distribution:

### 1. [Private Channel](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992)

**Pro:**

- all the benefits of Google play, but only visible to your internal users

**Contra:**

- requires all users to be in your Google Apps domain
- no targeting per user or group, will be available to everybody in the domain
- app can only be published to public or private channel, not both

---

### 2. [Custom .apk distribution](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html)

**Pro:**

- easy distribution (simply setup internal page or email with .apk link)

**Contra:**

- no automatic app updates via Google Play --> you need to implement an own mechanism
- users will have to deal with "unknown source" warning upon installation

---

### 3. [MDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) / [Android for Work](https://www.google.com/work/android/)

**Pro:**

- full control over who will get the app and updates

**Contra:**

- way higher effort and/or cost to implement and maintain

Answer (score 1):

you can use push-link.com, they would provide a great solution for you

Disclaimer : I'm a customer of them

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Beta distribution for a private community for test.

See [this](http://pugetworks.com/blog/2013/06/beta-testing-android-apps-on-the-google-play-store/) link

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Deploy apps for in-House usage](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/work.html). This is a late answer. But it might help someone.